# Different font sizes in the same editor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

Is there a way to show different fonts/font-sizes depending on whether it's a Java function name, or keyword, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, short of writing your own renderer.

Comment: That sounds quite complex Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no one else is going to say anything then I'll say no, there's no way to have different fonts and sizes in a single Text editor.  The editor has as part of its internal configuration a means to determine which text is a reserved word, comment, etc. and the editor framework is able to color the text based on that syntactic parsing.  However, there is no support for changing the font or font size of the text.